# Does bounded and closed equal compact for sets of Borel probability measures?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

Equip the space of Borel probability measures on a fixed closed subset X of the s-dimensional Euclidean space with the topology induced by weak convergence of probability measures. In this setting, does compact equal bounded and closed (with respect to the Kantorovich metric)? If not, is there a simple counterexample?